# Upgrading VC++ project from VS 2008 to VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I was upgrading a project from VS 2008 to VS 2010. I ran into following unresolved link error.

**LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR**

After doing some web search on the error...following link did point me into right direction.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vcgeneral/thread/af6796af-a1bf-4904-9923-15101956d882

But adding "int __forceCRTManifestCUR=0;" this to main file didn't work for me.

What I found out is that my original VS 2008 project properties under Linker->Command Line had additional option of /include:__forceCRTManifestCUR. This option worked fine in VS 2008
build but was giving link error in VS 2010.

After taking out this option, I was able to compile fine in VS 2010.

Question I have is...

1. What this include option /include:__forceCRTManifestCUR does? and
2. why it doesn't work in VS 2010?

Comment: It is one of gyrations for dealing with the manifest that ensures the proper runtime DLL is found from the Windows side-by-side cache.  This no longer exists in VS2010, you can remove the /include option.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have to write

```
extern "C" int _forceCRTManifestCUR=0
```

for it to work in C++, the original article forgets to mention this.